# How to set widget layouts in Android?

Tags: android, layout, widget

I know how to set the widget when it is a fixed size, such as 2x2; but how do I set it to resize or set orientation automatically? Do I just dump all the frame backgrounds in all the drawable folders and hope for the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at use of 9-patch images for backgrounds, explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html).